# Paradox with default c'tor potentially throwing for a class with a std::string member

Tags: c++, constructor, stdstring

Do the C++ "Core Guidelines" prevent (or, at least, strongly discourage) a class with a `std::string` member from having a default constructor? I ask because of an issue I've noticed when using the MSVC Code Analysis tool (in Visual Studio 2019) in its most 'severe' setting; the issue is the "C26455" warning, as discussed in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26455?view=msvc-170):

> The C++ Core Guidelines suggest that default constructors shouldn't do
> anything that can throw. If the default constructor is allowed to
> throw, operations such as move and swap will also throw which is
> undesirable because move and swap should always succeed. Parameterized
> constructors may throw.

The problem is illustrated in the following, trivial code sample (when compiled using the C++17 Standard – see the "edit" note, below):

```cpp
#include <string>

class Person {
private:
    std::string my_name;
public:
    // C26455: Default constructor may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept'...
    Person() : my_name{ "Anonymous" } {}

//  // C26447: The function is declared 'noexcept' but calls function 'allocator<char> >()' which may throw exceptions...
//  Person() noexcept : my_name{ "Anonymous" } {}
};
```

Now, if I heed the generated C26455 warning (as shown in the comment), and add the `noexcept` specifier to the default constructor (that commented-out in the code sample above), I get a different warning, indicating that my constructor calls a routine in the standard library that may throw:

> warning C26447: The function is declared 'noexcept' but calls function
> 'allocator >()' which may throw exceptions (f.6).

Note that I get the same warning if I remove the initializer list from the constructor and add that default value initializer to the declaration of the `my_name` member (as `std::string my_name{ "Anonymous" };`). However, all warnings disappear if I don't explicitly initialize the `my_name` member – which means I rely on the default constructor for `std::string` to create an empty object of unspecified capacity.

Presumably, another option would be to provide my own, non-throwing allocator, and pass that as the second argument to the `my_name` constructor – but this seems, to me, to be a somewhat over-complex solution to what must be a very common use case. (Similar situations would arise when using other standard library container objects as class members that require initialization involving allocation.)

Is there a simple resolution to this issue? Or should I just ignore/disable those code analysis warnings and core guidelines?

---

EDIT: Note that, when compiling to the C++20 Standard, the C26447 warning goes away when adding the `noexcept` specifier to the default constructor. I don't understand what C++20 offers that makes this happen; if I did, then maybe that would give a hint as to how to handle the situation for code compiled using the C++17 Standard (as I would prefer).

In my earlier (now deleted) answer, I speculated that it was that the string literal operator (`""s`) has a `constexpr` version from C++20 onwards, but it appears that this cannot, in itself, provide the explanation.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would a default constructor throwing imply that move and swap would also throw? A move constructor or a move assignment shouldn't involve the default constructor, and neither should a swap. Edit: I think I see it: A move constructor/assignment should leave the moved-from object in some state, which *could* be a default state. And swap typically uses moves. But it isn't a requirement.

Comment: You should just declare it `noexcept`. If default allocator throws then your program is not recoverable anyway - so termination is totally acceptible outcome. Also with short enough string the allocator won't be used.

Comment: Perhaps germane to this question are the numerous talks and proposals the standard committee have made regarding what to do about `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Just a note: Even Microsoft (one of the contributors to C++ Guidelines) does not always follows this rule. For instance, in MS STL, the default constructor of `std::map` can throw. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/nc7Y6jEMd.

Comment: A useful answer may depend first on the answer to this question - "What do you expect your program to do when the computer runs out of memory?"  A very common - but not exclusive - answer to that question in professional domains is "I expect it to terminate."

Comment: [Cpp core guidelines C.44: Prefer default constructors to be simple and non-throwing](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-default00).

Comment: BTW, the string is short and in MS STL, SSO is (IIRC) applied for up to [15 characters](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xstring#L2305). Therefore, the constructor of `std::string` should not allocate and, therefore, not throw (in theory at least :).

Comment: Funny, C.45's "good" example (similar to OP's one) violates so C.44.

Comment: @DanielLangr: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) default constructor is not marked `noexcept`... Don't *"blame"* Microsoft.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but implementations are allowed to make it `noexcept`. Such as libstdc++ and libc++ do.

Comment: @DrewDormann Well, in *some* circumstances, I may want the user to be presented with a message saying that a new class object can't be created, and maybe they should close/kill some of their existing ones. (Like in a multi-document app, to close some of their many open docs.)

Comment: @AdrianMole that sounds like a very reasonable scenario, which would work well when memory is running low, for some definition of "low".  If free-store allocations are already failing, you may discover that "presenting a message" will also fail, for the same reason.